# AngularJS app does not load on iPad / iPhone Safari (works only after page refresh / second load and afterwards)

Tags: angularjs, safari

I have a really weird issue with my AngularJS app on iPad / iPhone safari.

The issue occurs only of first load (after clearing history / website data).

The issue that the application wont start at all - I get a white page and the console (from MacBook develop tools) is full with errors,

Sometimes I'm getting lots of

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.module')
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd.$$minErr')
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.noop')
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
...
```

Sometimes I'm getting `Error: $injector:unpr` - `Unknown Provider`

And sometimes `Error: $injector:nomod` - `Unknown Provider`

**But if I hit page refresh after getting the white page / errors - all works just fine.**

This is part of the third party js libs/plugins I include on my index.html

```
<script src="resources/plugins/head.load.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/modernizr-custom.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.14.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/ng-table/ng-table.min.js"></script>

<script src="resources/lib/file-upload/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/lib/file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
```

I'm really lost here...

---

**Another thing:** I have noticed on my Mac (Resources->Scripts) that if I open a file, lets say Resources->Scripts->FileNameOne.js the content is actually of another file FileNameTwo.js ??? is it a flaw of the dev tools of the Mac that confuses the names/content or can it be related to the problem???

Any Ideas?

---

**Here is the complete solution with Grunt**

Content of the *Gruntfile.js*

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
      concat: {
        dist: {
          src: ['WebContent/resources/plugins/head.load.min.js', 'WebContent/resources/plugins/modernizr-custom.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js', 
                'WebContent/resources/lib/angular/angular.min.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/angular/angular-resource.min.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/angular/angular-route.min.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/angular-translate/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.14.1.min.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/ng-table/ng-table.min.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/websockify/util.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/websockify/base64.js', 'WebContent/resources/lib/websockify/websock.js',
                'WebContent/resources/lib/file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js', 
                'WebContent/resources/js/services/*',
                'WebContent/resources/js/services/dialogs/*',
                'WebContent/resources/js/controllers/*',
                'WebContent/resources/js/directives/*',
                'WebContent/resources/plugins/*'],
          dest: 'dist/myWebAppInOneFile.js',
        },
      },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat']);
};
```

Then just call *grunt* from the relevant folder and you'll get your file

Comment: are you clearing cache when you clear history and website data?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could be a problem with the sequence in which you're loading the files in the header. Which libraries are you using?

Comment: updated the question (with a list of included js files), as to the cache - I use the following options from settings -> safari, 1)Clear History and Website Data 2) Advanced -> Website Data -> -> Remove all Website Data, both of them clearing history, cookies and other browsing data (I guess it refers to cache too)

Comment: Sorry, but is it typo? or are you copy-pasting from browser console and it is really "undeined" ?

Comment: Can this be caused by the same issue as this one, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6696 ?

Comment: @SumanBarick , its a typo... and it doesn't look like its related to that issue

Comment: Can you provide any Plunker related to issue? I'm not able reproduce after looking problem.

Comment: I think this is a Angular Application Bootstrap issue. Can you show the full code of your index.html? I want to see the include statements for app.js and controllers.js. after that i can suggest you. thank you.

Comment: It certainly sounds like a race condition where some scripts are trying to load before their dependencies.  Do you get the same results if you strip it down to just angular.min.js?

Comment: I'm trying to strip it now and to see how it goes... will update here...

Comment: Are you using the jquery ready to bootstrap angular? Have you tried using load event instead?

Comment: Seems to be a well know problem with Safari. Many post is talking about non loaded web sites due to DNS-prefetching in Safari. Check this out
http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-fix-slow-and-non-loading-webpages-in-safari--mac-51338
And here is a link on how you can resolve this in your page http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/speed-up-your-site-using-prefetching/

Comment: @MarcusH , thanks, but I need a solution that can be applied to my web app (software) instead to the end users hardware

Comment: @42shadow42 , The error occurs even with using `<html lang="en" ng-app="csrApp">` (no jquery events involved at all)

Comment: @Daniel The last link shows you how you can solve this in your web app by adding <link href="..(your script).." rel="dns-prefetch" /> http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/speed-up-your-site-using-prefetching/

Comment: @MarcusH , its relevant for css only

Comment: Using a CDN after build, or is everything local?

Comment: I think the issue is with ng-inject could you show how do you inject your dependencies? Also, The order of files might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What build toolchain are you using. One option would be to concatenate all of the includes into a single file, this should stop the error where the wrong scripts are being loaded - As mentioned by [Marcus H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4870358/marcus-h)

**Gulp**
https://github.com/contra/gulp-concat

**Grunt**
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: Thanks, after using *grunt-contrib-concat* it started to work!

Comment: Glad it worked  - if you ever do find out the underlying cause it'd great to know

Comment: i have a strong feeling that safari loaded files with the wrong order / wrong content into wrong files