# Loading angular web application in the iOS UIWebView,it is not loading showing blank screen

Tags: ios, angularjs, uiwebview

Loading angular web application in the iOS UIWebView,it is not loading showing blank screen. We have inspected through mac browser and we are getting random errors. i.e angular not defined or angular module injection error. Site is working in Web browsers and Android Web View. Please help me out

Comment: share code you have written to load the url and error in logs if any

Comment: Do you use cordova?

Comment: We didn't use cordova

Comment: We are using load a web view **[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nsfWebPageLink]]]];**

Comment: Finally got a solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258617/angularjs-app-does-not-load-on-ipad-iphone-safari-works-only-after-page-refre